# Why do object rewrite another frozen object

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why my object overwrite another frozen object, i try to create a new instance from my previous object and then freeze it. But anyways, it's overwrites itself even if it's frozen
Also, why i can change my `check` object if it's `const`
JS is actaully weird

I have the code below

```
let obj = {check: "check"};  
const check = Object.create(obj);
Object.freeze(check);
obj["second"] = "something";
// Expected result: obj = {check: "check", second: "something"}
// check = {check: "check"}

// Actual result: obj = {check: "check", second: "something"}
// check = {check: "check", second: "something"}
```

Comment: It doesn't overwrite another object. `check` doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.create()` doesnot clone the object you should use `Object.assign`

```js
let obj = {check: "check"};  
const check = Object.create(obj);
Object.seal(check);
obj["second"] = "something";
console.log(check)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Object.create() method creates a new object, using an existing object as the prototype of the newly created object. The properties of the prototype are accessible to the child objects.

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

You have to use Object.assign() if you want to clone an object.